# How can I use a Google Script in Google Doc to automatically remove text AFTER the numbers in a numbered list?

Tags: google-apps-script, text, replace, numbered-list

I have a document which has a auto numbered list:
1.  text here
2.  text here

and I'd like the script to remove the text(and all the numbers except the #1 (the first item in the numbered list should remain):

So after the script, the document should show only the blank numbered list with no entries after the numbers:
1.
2.

I cannot search for a "1. " since it is a automatically numbered list.  All I want to be able to do is to remove the contents of the list but leave the numbers as a numbered list.

I tried

```
   var regExp2 = "[[:space:]]"
   docBody.replaceText("\n"+regExp2,"\n");
```

but get nothing.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your current issue and question.

Comment: What is your expected output?  Do you want the numbered list to be converted to individual paragraphs (i.e. a line of text for each item in the list)?

Comment: I just editted the posting ... I want to remove all the text on the numbered list and only have the numbers remaining (as I now show in the posting)

Comment: I think the OP's key words are "I cannot search for a "1. " since it is a **automatically numbered** list." (my emphasis).  So the OP wants to replace a dynamic/automatic "numbered list" with a static numbered list, with the numerals "1", "2", etc, each on new line.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this to work:

```
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var id_old=""
  for (var num=body.getListItems().length-1; num>=0; num--){
    var list = body.getListItems()[num];
    var id=list.getListId();
    list.clear();
    if (id==id_old){list.removeFromParent();}  //remove item from list if id of item is repeated
    id_old=id
  }
```

This successfully removes all but the first items in the list and clears first the entry in the list.